TimescaleDB carry forward then aggregate in buckets
I have a table that contains IoT updates from many devices. I'd like to calculate an average for each hour based on the device readings. I would like those readings to be carried forward before aggregating. I don't have readings for each hour, there are gaps.
Given a table:
stamp               | device_id | reading
2024-12-21 01:00:00 | 1         | 200
2024-12-21 02:00:00 | 2         | 500
2024-12-21 03:00:00 | 2         | 100

I would expect a result:
stamp               | average_reading
2024-12-21 01:00:00 | 200
2024-12-21 02:00:00 | 350 = (200+500)/2
2024-12-21 03:00:00 | 150 = (200+100)/2
2024-12-21 04:00:00 | 150 = (200+100)/2

I was playing with locf & avg and time_bucket_gapfill, but it seems that locf has to be a top function, so it can only carry forward a previous average, which is not what I want.
SELECT time_bucket_gapfill('1h', table.stamp) as bucket,
       locf(avg(reading))
FROM table
WHERE stamp >= '2024-12-21 01:00:00' 
  AND stamp < '2024-12-21 05:00:00'
GROUP BY bucket

I was trying to get prev of lcof somehow to get it done, but it doesn't seem possible to do it per device.
How can I do it?

This seems to work:
WITH filled_data AS (
    SELECT
        time_bucket_gapfill('1h', stamp) AS bucket,
        device_id,
        locf(avg(reading)) AS carried_forward_reading
    FROM iot_table
    WHERE stamp >= '2024-12-21 01:00:00' 
      AND stamp < '2024-12-21 05:00:00'
    GROUP BY bucket, device_id
)
SELECT
    bucket AS stamp,
    avg(carried_forward_reading) AS average_reading
FROM filled_data
GROUP BY bucket
ORDER BY bucket;

